# Fullcalendar 5 external event drop to resource timeline returns undefined even when extendedProp are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

New to Fullcalendar 5 - im using [eventContent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) to replace everything in the event.
When I drag external events to the calendar the event takes the "style" of the eventContent, but with undefined on on the same vars that do work in the eventContent on Calendar load.

[eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive) returns the event with all the data in the console, so its seems my new Draggable is sending data ...why won't it carry to the new event even though the drop style changes

Example of eventContent(working on load)

```
eventContent: function (info) {
        let italicEl = document.createElement('i')    
        
         italicEl.innerHTML = '<i class="nav-icon fa fa-clock"></i> '
         +info.event.extendedProps.mystart+'-'+info.event.extendedProps.mystart
         +'<span style="padding:0 10px;display:inline-block;width:50%; text-align:right">Team '
         +info.event.extendedProps.team+'</span>'
 ....
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you define the data of the external events? Perhaps they don't have these extended properties defined? We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to determine what exactly is happening.